# Tipos enumerados c++

Tags: c++

El programa trata de que al introducir un numero del 0 al 6, nos muestre el día de la semana correspondiente. No obstante no funciona debido seguramente al mal uso de los tipos enumerados (`enum tElemento`).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int numero;
 enum tElemento{Lunes,Martes,Miercoles,Jueves,Viernes,Sabado,Domingo};
 cout << "introduce un numero del 0 al 6:";
 cin >> numero;
 numero = tElemento;
 cout << tElemento;
}
```

Comment: "*No obstante no funciona*". ¿Qué es lo que no funciona?

Comment: No arranca, de hecho el error esta en el tElemento. Error: uso no valido de este tipo de instruccion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@PaperBirdMaster ya te ha comentado por qué no compila tu programa... pero entiendo que el problema que intentas solucionar es otro diferente.

Lo que entiendo que pretendes es convertir un número en una cadena. Así:

- 0 sería "Lunes"
- 1 sería "Martes"
- 2 sería "Miércoles"
- ...

Los tipos enumerados **no son cadenas**. Un enumerado es, por intentar definirlo de forma un poco vaga, como un número con nombre, lo cual dista mucho de una cadena de texto.

Los enumerados se usan para darle un significado especial y relevante a ciertos valores (sin necesidad de conocer dichos valores).

Así, en este enumerado:

```
enum Dias
{
  Lunes,
  Martes,
  Miercoles,
  Jueves,
  Viernes,
  Sabado,
  Domingo
};
```

`Miercoles` equivale al número 2, aunque dicho valor puede ser irrelevante... a ti lo que te interesa es saber si un dato introducido por el usuario o leído de un fichero se corresponde con el dado para `Miercoles`.

Lo que tu necesitas es convertir un entero en una cadena de texto y esto lo puedes hacer, a grandes rasgos, de dos formas diferentes:

Comprobar manualmente el valor introducido para devolver la correspondiente cadena:

```
cin >> numero;
std::string diaDeLaSemana;

switch( numero )
{
  case 0:
    diaDeLaSemana = "Lunes";
    break;

  case 1:
    diaDeLaSemana = "Martes";
    break;

  case 2:
    // ...
}
```

O bien puedes almacenar las cadenas en un arreglo y acceder a las mismas vía índice:

```
std::string dias[] = { "Lunes", "Martes", /* ... */ };

cin >> numero;
cout << dias[numero];
```

Answer (score 3):

Estás usando un tipo como un valor:

```
//      vvvvvvvvv <--- tipo
   enum tElemento{Lunes,Martes,Miercoles,Jueves,Viernes,Sabado,Domingo};
//    valores --> ^^^^^ ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^


//          vvvvvvvvv <--- tipo
   numero = tElemento;
//         vvvvvvvvv <--- tipo
   cout << tElemento;
```

Es como si vas al McDonalds y al preguntarte qué quieres comer dices "*una hamburguesa*" pero no dices cuál de todas. Seguramente querías usar un valor:

```
   enum tElemento{Lunes,Martes,Miercoles,Jueves,Viernes,Sabado,Domingo};

// vvvvvvvvv <--- Tipo
   tElemento numero;
//           ^^^^^^ <--- instancia

   cout << "introduce un numero del 0 al 6:";

   cin >> numero;
//        ^^^^^^ <--- instancia

   cout << numero;
//         ^^^^^^ <--- instancia
```

Sin embargo no te funcionará porque `std::cout` no tiene sobrecarga para el tipo `tElemento` así que deberás transformarlo en un tipo conocido tanto para leer como para escribir:

```
enum tElemento{Lunes,Martes,Miercoles,Jueves,Viernes,Sabado,Domingo};
tElemento numero;
cout << "introduce un numero del 0 al 6:";

cin >> static_cast<int>(numero);
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- conversion a entero (ERROR!)

cout << static_cast<int>(numero);
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- conversion a entero
```

Pero este truco te funcionará para escribir en consola pero no para leer, así que la mejor opción será sobrecargar los operadores de lectura/escritura de flujo de datos:

```
std::istream &operator >>(std::istream &i, tElemento &t)
{
    int v;
    i >> v;
    t = static_cast<tElemento>(v);
    return i;
}

std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const tElemento t)
{
    return o << static_cast<int>(t);
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Zpx3wii0hNDyQerx)</kbd>.